# Can't create task with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

Using device and can't create task
my models
user

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :tasks
end
```

task

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

task controller

```
  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and when trying to create task have an error

> 1 error prohibited this task from being saved:
>
> ```
> User must exist
> ```

my response

Started POST "/tasks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-27 14:20:59 +0200
Processing by TasksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"b7EkQsJygYBW1xLIm1uFD8jluXy2LYeoYjAOjKcwWOMHLwtalXmkTrNJu0yhexucwY94COegDcuVrOWLRkf8dg==", "task"=>{"title"=>"", "description"=>"", "priority"=>"", "due(1i)"=>"2017", "due(2i)"=>"12", "due(3i)"=>"27", "done"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create Task"}

```
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change `belongs_to :user` to  `belongs_to :user, optional: true`. Rails 5 has introduced default validation in associations. Refer [this link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/870) for better understanding

Comment: it works but not currectly. when i add to the new_task_view   <div class="field">\n
    <%= form.label :user_id %>\n
    <%= form.text_field :user_id, id: :task_done %>\n
  </div> \n it works how i whant, but i need the handly put user's id. I whant to do that automaticly

Answer (score 0):

in method create in controller need to add `@task.user_id = current_user.id`

Comment: This is an answer.  It could use more explanation, but it is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, that Task is not good name for model according to https://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/words/task?q[word_or_notes_cont]=task

In Rails there is not full list of reserved words because of the nature of the language and framework. But sometimes you can face strange behaviour, when you use conflicting keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing `user_id` for creating `task`

Try to the following

On your code

```
def create
  @task = Task.new(task_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @task.save
      format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Modified from your code, you can use that

```
def create
  @task = Task.new(task_params)
  @task.user = current_user

  respond_to do |format|
    if @task.save
      format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Hope to help